# When light hits my glasses, each lens shows different color

Tags: visible-light

So I was holding my glasses in a certain angle, and the light source is directly above it.

When looking through one lens, I see purple straight 'lines', and through the other lens the lines are teal.

I tried moving the glasses to the left and to the right, and at the previous position where the left side showed purple color, when my right lens is at that place, it keeps showing the right lens color - the teal color. (same result when moving it the other direction).

I tried flipping the glasses so the right lens is at the left's position and vice versa, and both lenses still show their colors. Even flipping the glasses so the light breaks through the other side of the lens (the "curvier" side of the lens instead of the other side), yields same results.

Does anyone have an explanation?

Thanks!

Comment: Hi & Welcome to Physics SE. I think this is due to a specific anti-glare coating on your lens. I notice this too on my current glasses but didn't notice it on my previous set.

Comment: Could you upload a photo or video of the phenomenon? May be it looks somewhat like this: https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/415640?